# Introducing termination as a precondition in Stainless

Tags: scala, formal-verification, stainless

I'm trying to proof that the evaluation of the untyped lambda calculus according to the following function:

```
 def eval(t: Term): Option[Term] = t match {
    case App(t1, t2) => eval(t1) match {
      case Some(Abs(x, body)) => eval(t2) match {
        case Some(v2) => eval(subst(x, v2, body))
        case None() => None[Term]()
      }
      case _ => None[Term]() // stuck
    }
    case _ => Some(t) // Abs or Var, already a value
  }
```

returns either None or a value. However, I was pointed out that this function might not terminate. My question is how can introduce as a precondition in Leon/Stainless that a function must terminate?

Comment: What is " Leon/Stainless" ?

Comment: @pedrofuria Leon is a software verification framework for Scala developed at EPFL. You can have more details in http://lara.epfl.ch/w/leon. Stainless is an upgrade of Leon but for this problem I don't think there will be much difference between the two.

Comment: Don't you want to make the compiler solve the halting problem, here? You would have to have some limited (subset of a) language, that can only accept terminating programs, but a whole Turing-complete language in general do not have such property.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, no that's not the aim here. The aim is to restrict the functions to the inputs on which it terminates. While this might not be decidable, there are systems which can deal with it nonetheless. It just means that whenever you call the function, you (the user) have to prove that it terminates on the arguments you have supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to introduce a precondition that specifically says "this function terminates (at the arguments given)". You should try to figure out a more high-level predicate which is equivalent to that. In your case, that's not going to work out, because you can't give a computable predicate that determines whether a term in untyped lambda calculus has a normal form.

Not all is lost though: The usual approach here is to introduce an additional "fuel" argument of type `BigInt`. It represents the maximal number of reduction steps to be performed. In each step, you decrement the fuel by one. If the fuel is zero, you abort the recursion and return `None`. This will trivially make your function terminate.

However, you always need to supply a "big enough" fuel. Usually the fuel will be a parameter and the lemma has a precondition that `eval(fuel, t) = Some(u)`.